# Checkout page error 'Email template '' is not defined'

Tags: magento2, error, email, email-templates, checkout-page

On checkout page I am getting error 'Email template '' is not defined'. I would like to know how can I debug this error to find out which email template is not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like error comes from the file `vendor/magento/module-email/Model/Template/Config.php` line 225:

```
/**
 * Retrieve value of a field of an email template
 *
 * @param string $templateId Name of an email template
 * @param string $fieldName Name of a field value of which to return
 * @return string
 * @throws \UnexpectedValueException
 */
protected function _getInfo($templateId, $fieldName)
{
    $data = $this->_dataStorage->get();
    if (!isset($data[$templateId])) {
        throw new \UnexpectedValueException("Email template '{$templateId}' is not defined.");
    }
    if (!isset($data[$templateId][$fieldName])) {
        throw new \UnexpectedValueException(
            "Field '{$fieldName}' is not defined for email template '{$templateId}'."
        );
    }
    return $data[$templateId][$fieldName];
}
```

I think somewhere in your code you (or someone else) forget to pass template id when calling a method.

**How to debug:**

xDebug is best choice :) But if you not familiar with it try this:

Temporally update the code from:

```
if (!isset($data[$templateId])) {
    throw new \UnexpectedValueException("Email template '{$templateId}' is not defined.");
}
```

to:

```
if (!isset($data[$templateId])) {
    $e = new \UnexpectedValueException("Email template '{$templateId}' is not defined.");
    echo $e->getTraceAsString();
    die();
}
```

then check trace on the checkout page, detect which method calling with empty `$templateId` and from where (it will be clear by trace). Update custom code from where error comes.

Trace can be seen in the Network tab of your browser and looks like this:

[image: trace]

Another place to debug is `vendor/magento/module-email/Model/Template.php` line 360 (method `processTemplate()`). Seems like some template have no id, so you can update code:

```
$templateId = $this->getId();
if (!$templateId) {
    $e = new \Exception('');
    echo $e->getTraceAsString();
    die();
}
```

Perhaps somewhere is a custom event handler in which magento try to send email with empty template.

Another hint: try to check the `email_template` table data, maybe some records is broken (has no id or something similar).

Comment: yes but I am not much aware of how to debug this

Comment: @Arjun I have update my answer, but it's hard to say something more about "how to debug that issue" with no access to the project :( Anyway good luck with debugging, I hope my advice will be useful to you.

Comment: thanks @Siarhey I got the template by trace. For timing I have disable the email code  my process is working fine. Thanks  for guidance